# Can I use a Linux VM as a complete desktop replacement over the top of MacOS?

Tags: macos, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I'd like to use Linux on my MBP.

While I am testing Asahi on a separate partition, there are certain things I need that are not yet available (BT, external display support). While I wait for that project to develop, I still have work that I need to do today so I am investigating using a Linux VM to replace my MacOS Desktop.

Linux VMs are working well on MacOS, with Parallels offering GPU paravituralization to get hardware acceleration working on the guest (is that Windows only?).

My issue is there doesn't seem to be a way to use any kind of "exclusive fullscreen" mode with a VM.

The top menu bar pops up when I move my cursor to the top of the screen and trackpad gestures are performed on the host rather than the VM (e.g. 3 finger swipe will change workspace on the MacOS host rather than the Gnome Linux guest)

I've only used UTM so far to experiment, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get a VM running in full screen mode such that MacOS is essentially disabled in the background until the VM is shutdown?

I want my MBP to run a Linux VM such that it feels like MacOS is not running in the background.